# How do i know when postgresql drops a table?

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to find in the logs to see when a table was dropped, but i cannot find it. I would like to know where does postgresql logs that information.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

First, *whether* it gets logged is up to you, based on your setting for [log_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT).  If you have chosen to log it, there are numerous other server configuration settings related to where the log entries are written and what information they contain.  (You may or may not be including such things as timestamp, user ID, IP address, etc., based on your chosen configuration settings.)